# How can I automate adding context to an Err?

Tags: rust

I'm parsing a text file line by line so I have a line number as context:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Position {
    pub line: usize,
    pub column: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ParseError {
    IoError(io::Error),
    InvalidRecord(Position),
    EncodingError(Position),
}
```

I have a loop like this:

```
let mut pos = Position { line: 0, column: 0 };
const LF: u8 = 0xa;
let mut record_buf = Vec::new();
while let Ok(nbytes) = reader.read_until(LF, &mut record_buf) {
    // if record_buf contains some special bytes, then
    // we have several numbers in ASCII
    let x = str::from_utf8(&record_buf[42..(42 + 2)])?.parse::<u32>()?;
    let y = str::from_utf8(&record_buf[46..(46 + 4)])?.parse::<u32>()?;

    //at the end
    record_buf.clear();
    pos.line += 1;
}
```

I want to automate mapping `Utf8Error` to `ParseError::EncodingError` and 
`ParseIntError` to `ParseError::EncodingError`.

I can not just implement `impl From<Utf8Error> for ParseError`,
because the context in the form of line number is not available in the trait implementation.

How can I simplify my coding and not write verbose error handling like this for every number that I want extract from `Vec<u8>`?

```
str::from_utf8(&record_buf[42..(42 + 2)])
    .map_err(|_| ParseError::EncodingError(pos.clone()))?
    .parse::<u32>()
    .map_err(|_| ParseError::InvalidRecord(pos.clone()))?
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a function which does reading and error conversion?

Comment: @red75prime I want solve problem in some more general way. I only start work on parsing, and parsing "header" lines, after that I have to handle many other errors and for all of them I want add line and column context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Use a crate like [quick_error](https://crates.io/crates/quick_error), [error-chain](https://crates.io/crates/error-chain), or [failure](https://crates.io/crates/failure).

---

> I can not just implement `impl From<Utf8Error> for ParseError`, because the context in the form of line number is not available in the trait implementation.

That's true, but that doesn't mean you can't produce a type that carries the context.

You can simplify your call site down to something like this:

```
let val = str::from_utf8(&record_buf[4..][..2])
    .context(pos)?
    .parse()
    .context(pos)?;
```

To do so, we create a new type to hold our combination context and original error, then implement an *extension trait* for `Result` to add the context to an error:

```
struct Context<V, E>(V, E);

trait ContextExt<T, E> {
    fn context<V>(self, v: V) -> Result<T, Context<V, E>>;
}

impl<T, E> ContextExt<T, E> for Result<T, E> {
    fn context<V>(self, v: V) -> Result<T, Context<V, E>> {
        self.map_err(|e| Context(v, e))
    }
}
```

We then implement `From<Context<...>> for Error` for each interesting thing:

```
impl From<Context<Position, str::Utf8Error>> for ParseError {
    fn from(other: Context<Position, str::Utf8Error>) -> ParseError {
        ParseError::EncodingError(other.0, other.1)
    }
}

impl From<Context<Position, num::ParseIntError>> for ParseError {
    fn from(other: Context<Position, num::ParseIntError>) -> ParseError {
        ParseError::InvalidRecord(other.0, other.1)
    }
}
```

The last ergonomic change is to implement `Copy` for your `Postion` type, which makes it much easier to use — no more calls to `.clone()`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5f0e2421a36ae77f95a35e16d1c91e4e&version=stable)

---

The aforementioned crates make this *way easier*.

Here's all the code with quick-error (my favorite):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;

use quick_error::ResultExt;
use std::{num, str};

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Position {
    pub line: usize,
    pub column: usize,
}

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum ParseError {
        EncodingError(pos: Position, err: str::Utf8Error) {
            context(pos: Position, err: str::Utf8Error) -> (pos, err)
        }
        InvalidRecord(pos: Position, err: num::ParseIntError) {
            context(pos: Position, err: num::ParseIntError) -> (pos, err)
        }
    }
}

fn inner_main() -> Result<u32, ParseError> {
    let record_buf = b"kode12abc";

    let pos = Position { line: 1, column: 2 };

    let val = str::from_utf8(&record_buf[4..][..2])
        .context(pos)?
        .parse()
        .context(pos)?;

    Ok(val)
}

fn main() {
    let v = inner_main().expect("boom");
    println!("{}", v)
}
```